# Avoiding Tab Line Change

Tags: c++, io

When you write input in C++, you verify that the input is over by pressing enter, sadly that also changes the line.
But I still want to output something in that particular line.

How can I stay there? Is there a way to change how you confirm the end of the input?

I'm using the Cygwin64 Terminal

Comment: C++ standard  I/O streams are just that ... streams. The C++ is not addressing from where these come and to where go. If you want to better control the terminal (to what standard I/O is typically directed) then you need to specify what kind of terminal and on what  operating system you use.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I'm using Cygwin64 Terminal with the C++11 standard on Windows

Comment: Not in standard C++.

Comment: To control Cygwin64 bash (in lot of far more sophisticated ways than you asked for) there must be /usr/lib/ncurses.h in your installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getline`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str;
    std::getline(std::cin, str, '.');
    std::cout << str;  
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
abcd.efgh
```

**Output**

```
abcd
```

Now `'.'` is an end of input.

---

[`getline` Reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Comment: This probably won't work, the terminal input usually only gets to the stream after pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

A simple `getline()` could be used. `getline()` takes in a delimiter character which can be utilized to "change how you confirm the end of the input". Without that parameter, the default delimiter is `\n`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    getline(cin, x, 'm');
    cout << x;
}
```

Input: `test1test2mtest3`
Output: `test1test2`

Special characters can also be used, like `\t`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string x;
    getline(cin, x, '\t');
    cout << x;
}
```

Input:

```
test1
test2
        test3
```

Output:

```
test1
test2
```

A downside that it would still requires users to press Enter to complete the input, as shown above. Because, as @Öö Tiib pointed out:

> C++ standard I/O streams are just that ... streams. The C++ is not
> addressing from where these come and to where go.

In other words, generally C++ can't control the terminal input/output system, it only knows if something is inputted or if something should be outputted, and feed that to the terminal.

Info : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline